# Simcom SIM 808 SIM900 Azure Iot Hub - authorization header not possible to add

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, sim900

I am using Simcom SIM 808 to post data to Azure Iot Hub. My problem is that Azure Iot Hub requires a SAS string in the Authorization header, but I can not find a way to add this header. Anyone have experience with sim 808 and Azure iot? Is it possible to add the authorization string to the url?

I am using the SIM800 series AT command manual v 1.07.pdf for reference.

Header arguments that are supported is:
CONTENT, USERDATA and some more.

Comment: Hi, Did you find an answer to this? I am stuck on the same problem

Answer (score 2):

Here you can find a program I made to send data to my Azure IoT Hub via HTTPS using SIMCOM Modules (SIM800, SIM900...): https://developer.mbed.org/users/BorjaTarazona/code/Azure_SIM800_HelloWorld/

I had the same issue, my problem was that you need to write before your shared access signature "Authorization: ". You need to use the argument "USERDATA" and the command will look like this:

`AT+HTTPPARA="USERDATA","Authorization: YourSharedAccessSignature"\r\n`

The commands I use to send data to Azure via HTTPS with SIMCOM modules are:

Initialization

1. Set context type: `AT+SAPBR=3,1,"CONTYPE","GPRS"\r\n`
2. Set APN: `AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","YourAPN"\r\n`
3. Open bearer: `AT+SAPBR=1,1\r\n`
4. Query bearer: `AT+SAPBR=2,1\r\n`
5. Enable HTTP functions: `AT+HTTPINIT\r\n`
6. Enable SSL: `AT+HTTPSSL=1\r\n`

Data transmission

7. Set bearer profile identifier: `AT+HTTPPARA="CID",1\r\n`
8. Set the URL: `AT+HTTPPARA="URL","YourURL"\r\n`
9. Set the shared access signature: `AT+HTTPPARA="USERDATA","Authorization: YourSharedAccessSignature"\r\n`
10. Set Content-Type field in the HTTP header: `AT+HTTPPARA="CONTENT","application/json"\r\n`
11. Set the JSON string to be sent: `AT+HTTPDATA=StringLength,20000\r\nYourJSONString`
12. HTTP POST: `AT+HTTPACTION=1\r\n`